# Error while init new class on function start

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

Why does it says that there is an argument missing when in code there is not ?

```
if correct:
            listOfCities = rmg.genRandomListOfPoints(self.numOfPointsVal,800,400)
            for algoType, isChoosen in self.checkBoxDict.items():
                if isChoosen.get():
                    print(algoType)
                    p = mp.Process(target = self.run(listOfCities,  self.numOfPointsVal, algoType))
                    p.start()
            # close this windows, it is longer no necessary
            self.destroy()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self, listOfCities, numOfPointsVal, algoType):
        """ Starts other window from new process"""
        t =  InitFrame.__init__(listOfCities, numOfPointsVal , algoType)
```

** Consol output **

In the output it says that 1 is missing but that is not true.

It is not IDE depending

```
pmx
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\git\WarsawSchoolOfAI\GeneticsAlgorithms\StartFrame.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    startButton = tk.Button(text = "Start", bd = 3, bg = "#20aa20", command = lambda:self.start())
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\git\WarsawSchoolOfAI\GeneticsAlgorithms\StartFrame.py", line 97, in start
    p = mp.Process(target = self.run(listOfCities, algoType))
  File "C:\Users\CrazyUrusai\git\WarsawSchoolOfAI\GeneticsAlgorithms\StartFrame.py", line 104, in run
    t =  InitFrame.__init__(listOfCities,  self.numOfPointsVal, algoType)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'algoType'
```

Comment: You can't call the `__init__` function like this: `t =  InitFrame.__init__(listOfCities,  self.numOfPointsVal, algoType)`. What do you want to do with this line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an object, you should not do that:

```
t =  InitFrame.__init__(listOfCities,  self.numOfPointsVal, algoType)
```

but that:

```
t =  InitFrame(listOfCities,  self.numOfPointsVal, algoType)
```

(An error is raised because when a method is called with the class name: `InitFrame.method()`, nothing is passed to the `self` argument)

Comment: I was doing this it ealier like this in code but had something else changed. Thanks.